# Создание класса

Tags: delphi, классы

Здравствуйте! 
Описал класс "Круг" и его потомок "Цилиндр" с функциями по нахождению их площадей. Но загвоздка в том, что данные (радиус, высота), которые мы берем из edit'ов, не знаю как описать, чтобы они относились к данному классу и чтобы они брались точно из edit'ов.      
        Описание класса:

```
interface
Type
TCircle = class
  public
  constructor Create;
    function Area:real;
    end;

  TCylinder = class(TCircle)
  public
  constructor Create;
  function Area:real;

end;

implementation
 Constructor TCircle.Create;
     begin
        inherited Create;
     end;
     function TCircle.Area;
     var
         radius:integer;
         pi:real;
     begin
         pi:=3.14;
         result:=radius*radius*pi;
     end;

   Constructor TCylinder.Create;

     begin
        inherited Create;
     end;
     function TCylinder.Area;
     var
       radius,height:integer;
       pi:real;
     begin
       pi:=3.14;
       result:=2*pi*radius*(radius+height);
     end;
```

В этой процедуре нужно указать, что для каждого класса мы берем значения из edit'ов:

```
procedure TCircles.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex=-1 then
      begin
         ShowMessage('Выберите фигуру');
         end;
         if (Circle is TCircle) then
         begin
               //ступор на этом месте
         end;

      end;
```

Помогите советом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то вам в ваших классах не хватает свойств, потому некуда вводить радиус и высоту.

Есть как минимум два варианта работы: объявить *публичные поля* или, если надо больше контроля - объявить *свойства*.

[**Публичные поля**](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/Public.php.html) объявить проще:

```
TCircle = class
  public
    Radius: integer;
    // ваши методы
end;
```

[**Свойства**](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/Property.php.html) чуть сложнее:

```
TCircle = class
  protected
    fRadius: integer;
  public
    Property Radius: integer read getRadius write setRadius;
    // ваши методы
end;

implementation

function TCircle.getRadius: integer;
begin 
  // ...
end;

function TCircle.setRadius(Value: Integer): integer;
begin
  // value - присваиваемое значение
end;
```

**Обратиться** в обоих случаях можно будет таким образом:

```
some_var := Circle.Radius; // считали
Circle.Radius := some_var; // записали
```

По ссылкам можно найти подробности вроде того, когда и стоит ли использовать публичные поля или свойства. Вернее, там советуют как раз свойства :)

Что же касается наследования, то это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вы шутите? Что за дурь:

     Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то вам в ваших классах не хватает свойств

Comment: Каким другим образом можно передать тот же радиус в объект?

Comment: Наследованием, например! Почитайте базовые принципы ООП! Если есть 10 фигур и для каждой надо вычислять площадь по одинаковым данным, то вы тупо будете описывать 10 классов с идентичным набором полей? Или создадите один абстрактный и уже в наследниках реализуете уникальный для каждого функционал?

Comment: Передача параметра в объект с помощью наследования? Да это же новое слово в программировании :)

Comment: По поводу наследования. Наследовать цилиндр от окружности логично только в геометрии. Логичнее наследовать Shape2D->Circle->Ellipse и Shape3D->Sphere->Cylinder. Идти нужно по пути расширения количества свойств и методов. А в circle->cylinder идет кроме расширения еще и переопределение. ибо area (площадь) для двумерного объекта не совсем то же самое что area (площадь поверхности) для трехмерных объектов. Кроме того, для каждого трехмерного наследника от circle придется вводить одинаковую сущность - объем, нехорошо.

Comment: Чтобы использовать физическую связь окружности и цилиндра допустимо в цилиндре использовать поле с типом окружность для описания основания и вычисления площади оснований как части формулы площади поверхности и объема.

Comment: Согласен. Чтобы не сбивать с толку читающих подправил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае было бы логично сделать базовый абстрактный класс TShape( фигура ) и уже от него наследовать ваши "TCircle" и "TCylinder". Так как в вашем случае радиус и высота присутствуют в обоих наследниках( "TCircle" и "TCylinder" ), то было бы умно вынести эти поля в базовый класс. И если вы не желаете делать их доступными напрямую из объекта класса, то поместите из в секцию "private". В нем же( в базовом классе ) создавайте абстрактный метод нахождения площадей, который будет реализован в наследниках. ( здесь наблюдается паттерн [Шаблонный метод](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED%ED%FB%E9_%EC%E5%F2%EE%E4_(%F8%E0%E1%EB%EE%ED_%EF%F0%EE%E5%EA%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF)) )

Comment: что есть высота в circle?

Comment: Как утверждает ТС)))

Comment: *(Вдруг кому-нибудь будет интересно почитать)*

- Вынос высоты и радиуса в класс `TShape` - это забавно и оригинально :)

- Пример с наследованием фигур, вообще говоря, сугубо академический, хороший пост на тему - [`http://insidecpp.ru/art/8/`][1].

- Паттерн `Template Method` у `GoF` все-таки предполагает наличие некоего унифицированного алгоритма, который кастомайзится в наследниках, а без приведения этого алгоритма говорить о шаблонном методе довольно-таки бессмысленно. *Просто виртуальная функция* - это еще не шаблонный метод

[2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principl